# Java Play query parameter delimiters

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.2, query-string, playframework-routing

I was wondering what query parameter delimiter is the Java play framework expecting.

I retrieve my query parameters in my action method like so:

```
Map<String, String[]> qMap = request().queryString();
```

I expect a list of doubles in one of the parameters, so I extract them like so:

```
double lat = Double.parseDouble(qMap.get("point")[0]);
double lon = Double.parseDouble(qMap.get("point")[1]);
```

I expected I could pass these parameters with the following query:

```
?point=2,3
```

But this rendered a `NumberFormatException`:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2,3"
```

So how can I pass an array of values for a single query parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass multiple values for the same query string variable construct a query string like this:

```
?point=2&point=3
```

That will give you a query string map like so:

```
{ point = [ "2", "3" ] }
```

That said, you may also consider using two separate parameter names:

```
?lat=2&lon=3
```

... resulting in:

```
{ lat = [ 2 ], lon = [ 3 ] }
```